# Auto-mounting to a directory other than /media in Fedora 13

Tags: fedora, mount, automounting, media, udev

I am using Fedora 13. I need to be able to configure how media are mounted automatically. For an example, I want to change the parent of all mounted media to be a directory other than /media. All the material on the Internet seem to be old. I grepped the rules.d of udev but could not find any reference to /media.

Could anybody know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automounting in a Fedora installation with Gnome as the desktop environment is done by nautilus. You can turn this feature on / off by tweaking the key /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount in gconf-editor. However, I don't think it is configurable. In the olden times, this was done by gnome-volume-manager which called gnome-mount. There you could tweak e.g. the name of the entry in /media which was used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using autofs?

Did you check `/etc/auto.master` and `/etc/auto.*`?

Comment: No, the package autofs is not installed but CDs and USB drives are still auto-mounted. I don't have any file under /etc starting with aut*