# Customize Drive Mount Location

Tags: linux, mount, external-hdd, volume, thunar-volman

I'm running Crunchbang Linux (a variant of Debian)

Whenever I plug in a drive, it gets mounted to `/media/username/UUID-or-Name`. Is there a way to instead mount it to `/media/UUID-or-Name`?

Crunchbang comes with `thunar-volman` installed by default, and I think it's what mounts the drives automatically, but there's no setting I can find that determines where drives are mounted, only whether or not they're mounted.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the automounting has the path `/media` hardcoded into the automounting tool.

See this previously asked question about Thunar, titled: [Make thunar mount drives into /media rather than /run/media/username?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/make-thunar-mount-drives-into-media-rather-than-run-media-username).

This question too is relevant, titled: [Auto-mounting to a directory other than /media in Fedora 13](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/auto-mounting-to-a-directory-other-than-media-in-fedora-13)

This was also the case when I looked into doing this with GNOME and the Nautilus automounter for USB drives. It always puts them under `/media` too, and it isn't configurable.

I think the easiest thing to in your case is to create a link at `/media/BLAH` that links to `/media/username/BLAH`.